# ¿Cómo enviar un dato por un puerto Serie con Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, serialport

Tengo un joystick conectado al puerto A0 y quiero enviar el dato leido a otro Arduino por un puerto serie. Para ello tengo este código "Emisor":

```
//Puerto joystick
const int jugador2 = A0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  int lectura = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(lectura);
  delay(100);
}
```

Para recibir el código tengo el código "Receptor":

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    int posJugador2 = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(posJugador2);
  }
  delay(100);

}
```

El programa "Emisor" lee correctamente los datos, ya que obtengo lecturas en un rango de 0 a 1024.
El problema lo tengo con el valor recibido por el "Receptor", ya que no lee los valores emitidos. Esto es lo que obtengo por el puerto serie del "Receptor":

```
62
62
62
62
62
62
62
62
62
```

Y esto lo que obtengo en el "Emisor"

```
524
524
522
522
523
524
522
524
523
524
```

Los cables de los puertos RX y TX están conectados correctamente, por lo que supongo que el problema lo tengo con el software en si.

Comment: El problema es que `println()` manda una **cadena de caracteres** por la serial, mientras que `read()` sólo extrae **un byte/caracter** cada vez. Lo más simple es que uses `Serial.parseInt()` para leer el valor en caracteres y devolverlo transformado en `int`.

Comment: Ha funcionado ¿Existe alguna función que envie directamente el entero sin necesidad de usar el Serial.parseInt()? Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serial.print` y `Serial.println` envían información como texto. Con `read` solo lees un caracter/byte.

Cómo mencionó Candid Moe, necesitas leer los caracteres y convertirlos en un tipo numérico con `Serial.parseInt`.

---

Para leerlos directamente puedes usar `Serial.readBytes` y `Serial.write` transmitiendo los bytes de cualquier tipo fundamental.

Es necesario que el emisor y el receptor tengan el mismo [endianness](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) y sus tipos sean del mismo tamaño así no tendrás problemas.

Por ejemplo, con un `int`:

```
// Emisor
int entero = 1234;
Serial.write((char*)&entero, sizeof(int));

// Receptor 
int entero = 0;
Serial.readBytes((char*)&entero, sizeof(int));
```

Aquí es donde se agrega complejidad:

- Si el receptor y el emisor no tienen el mismo **endianess**, el número leído será diferente al original. Deberás invertir el orden de sus bytes para que lo interprete correctamente.
- Si los tipos son de diferente tamaño, tendrás que usar un tipo con el tamaño equivalente.

  Por ejemplo, si `int` en el emisor es de 2 bytes y en el receptor es de 4, estarías leyendo información demás. Si `short` es de 2 bytes en el receptor, puedes leerlo así.

  ```
  // Emisor
  int entero = 1234;
  Serial.write((char*)&entero, sizeof(int));

  // Receptor 
  short entero = 0;
  Serial.readBytes((char*)&entero, sizeof(short));
  ```